# SVG color not changing

Tags: css, svg

For a project, we've been using SVG images. I'm trying to color them but without success, here's the SVG:

```
<svg id="Calque_2" data-name="Calque 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 313.89 311.93">
<defs>
    <style>
        .cls-1 {
            fill: #fff;
            opacity: 0.3;
        }
    </style>
</defs>
<title>goutte_background</title><path
    class="cls-1"
    d="M1145.43,987.78c-45,0-81.7-35.18-82.09-79.35v-4.3h0a63.88,63.88,0,0,1,2-14.07,90.58,90.58,0,0,1,6.25-17.2c13.68-30.49,38.7-63.33,38.7-63.33,18.76-26.58,27.36-46.91,30.88-59.81a147.8,147.8,0,0,0-57.07,12.12,158.6,158.6,0,0,0-83.26,83.26,151.14,151.14,0,0,0-12.12,60.59c0,21.5,3.91,41.83,12.12,60.59a158.6,158.6,0,0,0,83.26,83.26c18.76,8.21,39.09,12.12,60.59,12.12h2c21.5,0,41.83-3.91,60.59-12.12a158.6,158.6,0,0,0,83.26-83.26c8.21-18.76,12.12-39.09,12.12-60.59a151.14,151.14,0,0,0-12.12-60.59,158.6,158.6,0,0,0-83.26-83.26,147.8,147.8,0,0,0-57.07-12.12c3.52,12.9,12.12,33.23,30.88,59.81,0,0,25,32.84,38.7,63.33a90.58,90.58,0,0,1,6.25,17.2,63.88,63.88,0,0,1,2,14.07h0v4.3c-0.39,44.17-37.14,79.35-82.09,79.35h-0.39Z"
    transform="translate(-988.68 -749.72)"/><path
    class="cls-1"
    d="M1145.43,778.26l1.56,6.25c2,8.21,7.82,25.8,24.63,49.64,0,0,18.76,24.24,28.93,46.91a62.83,62.83,0,0,1,4.69,12.9,32.92,32.92,0,0,1,1.56,10.55h0v3.13c0,32.84-27.36,59-61,59h-0.39c-33.62,0-61-26.19-61-59v-3.13h0A32.93,32.93,0,0,1,1086,894a62.83,62.83,0,0,1,4.69-12.9c10.16-22.67,28.93-46.91,28.93-46.91,16.81-23.84,22.67-41.43,24.63-49.64Z"
    transform="translate(-988.68 -749.72)"/></svg>
```

I'm currently using this SVG as a background for a `div`, and I'm struggling to change it's color.

Here's what I've tried:

.someParent .cls-1 {
  fill: #0080FF !important;
}

and

```
.someParent svg {
  fill: #0080FF !important;
}
```

I've also been trying to remove the `style` of the SVG but this had no effect.

This is the CSS for using the SVG as my div background:

```
background: #ffffff url("../images/goutte_background.svg") no-repeat right top;
```

Comment: CSS doesn't know nested selectors. I think `.someParent .cls-1 { /*...*/ }` or `.someParent svg { /*...*/ }` is what you're looking for.

Comment: My bad, i'm using sass

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can't adjust the SVG fill if it's a background-image. See: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-6.
>
> A possible solution is to inline the SVG so you can modify its fill
>   color, then absolutely position it behind what you want it to be
>   behind.

As Timolawl said, that was it.
I've used a different trick, i simply have duplicated the image and changed the color in the `style` tags

Answer (score 8):

You can't adjust the SVG fill if it's a background-image. See: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-6.

A possible solution is to inline the SVG so you can modify its fill color, then absolutely position it behind what you want it to be behind.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, just wanted to make sure. Any idea why it doesn't work if it's a bg-image ?

Comment: @Jorel Amthor Not entirely sure. My gut feeling is that the internals of background-image aren't accessible to the DOM, hence you can't style them. Whereas, if you inline the SVG, the internals can be manipulated.

Comment: @JorelAmthor because CSS applies per document and the image is a separate document. Also the semantics of images are designed to be consistent which means like rasters.